# NDB Cluster DataNode Consuming much RAM

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-cluster

I have set up NBC Cluster at my Office. There are two physical Machines with 128G/each. The database size is around 2G. We are an ISP and we have kept the RADIUS database in the cluster.

The thing that is worrying me at the moment is, in both the Systems, the process is consuming 122G each out of 128 and I think its shocking. 
I am quite new to database so I am having trouble debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The memory used by NDB data nodes is defined by your cluster
configuration. So even if the database is only 2GB in size, if you
have configured to run with up to 64 GByte of memory, this memory
is preallocated to ensure that it is there when it is needed.

So look into your config.ini file to see how you configured the
NDB data nodes.

Comment: Here's the outout of the config.ini:

Comment: Hello Sir, 
May I have your email address?
Thank you.